# How to use Python multiprocessing in a package/module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to use `multiprocessing` in a Python module (on Windows). I've been reading about the reasoning behind the required `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement that should precede calls to `multiprocessing`'s tools, to "protect the entry point of the program." However, if I'm going to use `multiprocessing` in a module and import it as part of a larger package, the `__name__` variable will always be the name of the module, won't it?

How can I use `multiprocessing` in an imported submodule and "protect the entry point" at the same time?

Here are the relevant parts of the code I'm trying to run:

```
import multiprocessing

def _redistribute_pumping(S1, E1, S2, E2, P2):
    #variable for redistributed pumping
    P1 = multiprocessing.Array('d', np.zeros((len(S1),)))
    #setup a list of processes
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=_inner_distribution,
            args=(S1[idx], E1[idx], S2, E2, P2, idx, range(len(S2)), P1)
            ) for idx in range(min_idx, max_idx + 1)]
    #run the processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    #exit the completed processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print P1
```

and I get this error:

```
RuntimeError:
        Attempt to start a new process before the current process
        has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
        forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
```

Comment: Can you link what you have been reading? It sounds as if you have misunderstood it. You shouldn't have `__name__ == '__main__'` guards in most Python modules (unless it's to execute doctests or something).

Comment: Section 16.6.3.2 in here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

Comment: This should only be relevant if you would want to call your module directly. If it is meant to be imported by scripts, just make sure to not start anything multiprocessing-related on top level in your module. Wrap it into functions, classes, or methods, for example.

Comment: I see. I understand where they were coming from; it's just kind of a bad example. When Python imports your module it executes all the source code once. Since that module's source code has multiprocessing start calls at the top level, those would run too. Just make sure it doesn't start doing anything like that until you are ready (call a function or something).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/3601/multiprocessing#t=201608011852436255572

Comment: Ok, I'll give it another try. While I'm asking, the program  is a `for` loop within a `for` loop. Calculations are performed for every pair of elements in two arrays and the results are sent to a third array. The third array needs to be shared between the processes/workers though. Best way to implement this with `multiprocessing`?

Comment: I tried the above edits

Comment: The relevant bits are the smallest amount of code that reproduces your problem. See [mcve] for more info